# Grails Domain Object Not Being Persisted

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Grails 3.2.10, Gorm 6.1.4, Hibernate 5.2.9

I have a grails domain object and a corresponding controller which performs basic crud operations (it is NOT scaffolded).  When submitting the Command object to the controller's update method, the controller performs as expected (all log messages are printing as they should) and NO error is being thrown.  The redirect page is shown like you would expect with the flash message displayed (even with the updated data).  However, the database value does not actually update.  I can create objects, it only does this for updates.

Answer (score 2):

After much frustration, it appears that the latest Gorm or Hibernate is monitoring the `setXXX` methods on the domain objects, and if those methods haven't been called hibernate will not see the object as modified and will not update any changes.  Turning up the log levels helped me see that hibernate was not seeing the object as modified, and thus ignoring it.

My problem centered around having `setData(CommandObject)` methods inside the domain objects which were calling `this.xxx = CommandObject.xxx;` thus by-passing the generated setters and causing hibernate to think the object was not modified.

Calling the setters directly from the controller is a work around for this issue.

---

**Example (which does NOT work):**

```
class Person {
  String name
  //...typical constraints, methods, etc...
  void setData(PersonCommand c){
    this.name = c.name;
  }
}

class PersonController {
  //...typical list, show, create methods...
  def update(PersonCommand pc){
     //... validation ...
     Person p = Person.get(pc.personId);
     p.setData(pc);
     p.save(failOnError: true);
     flash.message = "Successfully saved person ${p.name}"
     redirect(action: 'show', id: p.id)
  }
}
```

**FIXED EXAMPLE (which DOES work):**

```
class Person {
  String name
  //...typical constraints, methods, etc...
}

class PersonController {
  //...typical list, show, create methods...
  def update(PersonCommand pc){
     //... validation ...
     Person p = Person.get(pc.personId);
     p.name = pc.name;
     //... set other fields ...
     p.save(failOnError: true);
     flash.message = "Successfully saved person ${p.name}"
     redirect(action: 'show', id: p.id)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a well-known domain class gotcha. You have to call the setters or getters inside other domain class' methods EXPLICITLY:

```
class Person {
  String name
  void setData(PersonCommand c){
    setName c.name
  }
}
```

Also I'd rename `setData()` to smth like `applyData()` to avoid collisions with POGOs methods

Comment: Odd thing was this code worked fine prior to Gorm 6 and Hibernate 5.